# Jquery result in its relative div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem that i have multiple DIVs with almost same ID but having increments from **0** to **any number** in the end, I want to use this username check function for every different username field and show its results in its specific related div. I tried all the possible ways but its not working.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skr312zm/)

Here is my Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=Loading]').hide();    
});

function check_username(){

    var username = $("[id^=username]").val();
    if(username.length > 1){
        $('[id^=Loading]').show();
        $.post("username-Check.php", {
            username: $('[id^=username]').val(),
        }, function(response){
            $('[id^=Info]').fadeOut(2100);
             $('[id^=Loading]').fadeOut(2100);
                setTimeout("finishAjax('Info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 2000);
        });
        return false;
    }
}

function finishAjax(id, response){

  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incremental/dynamic `id` attributes are almost always an anti-pattern and should be avoided where possible as they create more problems than they solve.

A much better solution would be to use DOM traversal to find the elements related to the one which raised the event - in your case the `blur` on the `input`.

To do this, firstly use unobtrusive event handlers instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. Then change the `id` attributes to classes. To find the elements, use the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the event, then `prev()` and `prevAll().first()` to find the required element by its class. Finally, provide an anonymous function to `setTimeout()` over hacking together a string to be run through `eval()`. Try this:

```
<div class="info"></div>
<span class="loading"></span>
<input class="username form-control" type="text" name="txtengine" placeholder="914899" value="" /><br>

<div class="info"></div>
<span class="loading"></span>
<input class="username form-control" type="text" name="txtengine" placeholder="914899" value="" /><br>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loading').hide();
});

$('.username').on('blur', function() {
    var username = $(this).val();
    if (username.length) {
        var $loading = $(this).prev('.loading').show();
        var $info = $(this).prevAll('.info').first();

        $.post("username-Check.php", {
            username: username,
        }, function(response) {
            $info.fadeOut(2100);
            $loading.fadeOut(2100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $info.html(response).fadeIn(2000);
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/skr312zm/3/)

Note that the example in the fiddle had the AJAX request logic amended to fit jsFiddles' JSON response logic, but the functionality is the same.

Comment: I added a fiddle to show it working. If it doesn't work for you, check the console for errors. Please also give more useful feed back than 'it doesn't work'

Comment: it works but only with first two text boxes when i have more text boxes it wont work at all

Comment: If those boxes are added to the DOM after the page has loaded you'll need to use a delegated event handler: `$(document).on('blur', '.username', function() { ....`

Comment: i made it work but can you do me a favor if you can exclude JSON post and try to work it with my old code so it will get my database result possible?

Comment: That's exactly what the code in the snippet example above is doing

Comment: worked thanks by making little changes into it thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Before I start answering I would strongly suggest you to use a class and then select via class name. As it seems your case is textbook for when to use jquery class-selectors.

You cannot use the attribute selector without specifying what you are using it on. I.e. you cannot say:

```
$('[id^=Loading]')
```

you need to give the tag name, the id, or the class i.e.

```
$('span[id^=Loading]')
```

I have made a jfiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/acc069me/6/